# Pandas Grouper by frequency with completeness requirement

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have monthly time series data that is both missing some entries and has scattered NaN values for other reasons. I need to aggregate the data into Quarterly and Annual series, but I do not want to report data for quarters/years with missing data. For example, in the data below, I do not want to report data for Q1 2014 because I am missing January of that year.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([
  ('Monthly','2014-02-1', 529.1),
  ('Monthly','2014-03-1',  67.1),
  ('Monthly','2014-04-1', np.nan), 
  ('Monthly','2014-05-1', 146.8),
  ('Monthly','2014-06-1', 469.7),
  ('Monthly','2014-07-1',  82.9),
  ('Monthly','2014-08-1', 636.9),
  ('Monthly','2014-09-1', 520.9),
  ('Monthly','2014-10-1', 217.4),
  ('Monthly','2014-11-1', 776.6),
  ('Monthly','2014-12-1',  18.4),
  ('Monthly','2015-01-1', 376.7),
  ('Monthly','2015-02-1', 266.5),
  ('Monthly','2015-03-1', np.nan),
  ('Monthly','2015-04-1', 144.1), 
  ('Monthly','2015-05-1', 385.0),
  ('Monthly','2015-06-1', 527.1),
  ('Monthly','2015-07-1', 748.5),
  ('Monthly','2015-08-1', 518.2)],
  columns=['Frequency','Date','Value'])

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.set_index(['Frequency','Date'],inplace=True)
df

                      Value
Frequency Date
          2014-02-01  529.1
          2014-03-01   67.1
          2014-04-01    NaN
          2014-05-01  146.8
          2014-06-01  469.7
          2014-07-01   82.9
          2014-08-01  636.9
          2014-09-01  520.9
          2014-10-01  217.4
          2014-11-01  776.6
          2014-12-01   18.4
          2015-01-01  376.7
          2015-02-01  266.5
          2015-03-01    NaN
          2015-04-01  144.1
          2015-05-01  385.0
          2015-06-01  527.1
          2015-07-01  748.5
          2015-08-01  518.2
```

I have tried using the Grouper function, but groupby ignores NaN values and the Grouper utility does not enforce time series completeness as far as I can tell:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(level='Date', freq='Q')).sum()

             Value
Date
2014-03-31  1571.2
2014-06-30   616.5
2014-09-30  1240.7
2014-12-31  1012.4
2015-03-31   643.2
2015-06-30  1056.2
2015-09-30  1266.7
```

What I would like to see is this:

```
             Value
Date
2014-03-31     NaN  # Because of missing 2014-01-01
2014-06-30     NaN  # Because of NaN in 2014-04-01
2014-09-30  1240.7
2014-12-31  1012.4
2015-03-31     NaN  # Because of NaN in 2015-03-01
2015-06-30  1056.2
2015-09-30     NaN  # Because of missing 2015-09-01
```

What's a good way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to write your own aggergate function, 1, if there are `nan`, return a `nan`; 2, if the period is too short, also return `nan`; 3, otherwise, return the sum:

```
In [43]:

gpy = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(level='Date', freq='Q'))

print gpy.agg(lambda x: np.nan if (np.isnan(x).any() or len(x)<3) else x.sum())

             Value
Date              
2014-03-31     NaN
2014-06-30     NaN
2014-09-30  1240.7
2014-12-31  1012.4
2015-03-31     NaN
2015-06-30  1056.2
2015-09-30     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a boolean mask which is True for each group which has exactly 3 elements:

```
mask = (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(level='Date', freq='Q'))['Value'].count() != 3).values
```

and then simply set the corresponding rows to NaN.

```
grouped = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(level='Date', freq='Q'))
result = grouped.sum()
mask = (grouped['Value'].count() != 3).values
result.loc[mask, 'Value'] = np.nan
```

yields

```
             Value
Date              
2014-03-31     NaN
2014-06-30     NaN
2014-09-30  1240.7
2014-12-31  1012.4
2015-03-31     NaN
2015-06-30  1056.2
2015-09-30     NaN
```